# Protected Sheets in Excel Service

Tags: sharepoint

Sharepoint Excel Services does not seem to support protected Sheets. Is there any other way to make some sheets read-only and make it work in Excel Services?

Answer (score 0):

Expose the values you need as references in another sheet. Publish the other sheet in place of the protected one.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I have tried your sugestion, but still the error arrise while opening the excel in excel services "Some of the sheet's protected"

Comment: How do you plan to expose the workbook in Excel Services to the users?